# Strategy iOS Notifications

Tags: ios, background, notifications, fetch

I have data per region (400) on a server. The data will change every day. The user/smartphone has a config-file with different regions as favorite. Every day the Android-App looks in the background on the server if new data for his region available. If yes a notification will display.

On iOS (Swift) that's impossible for me to do the same.
With Background Fetch and local notificatons it will work from time to time, but not always.
Then I try it with silent remote notifications (every day), but here is the same problem.

What is the right strategy or way to do this under iOS:
1. The user has different regions as favorite
2. On the server are data from all regions
3. Every day the smartphone compare the regions if new data on the server and notify the user

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Push Notification. The server will send the push notification to the device / app when new data updates on server for particular favorite region.

The user should send the list of favorite region to the server.

Comment: Ok, that does it mean, the configuration of all users will send and update on the server, I feared it.

Comment: It will send update to only those users who registered for the particular favorite region.